# Pre-populate Text Input With Object Values React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, foreach

I'm trying to pre-populate text fields with pre-existing data in an object. I'm using a component renderer which is built from a switch statement like so (I'll remove the other cases to make it more readable):

```
switch (data.type) {
    case 'text':
        return (
            <div
                key={data.index}
                data-name={selection}
            >
                <FieldLabel
                    htmlFor={data.name}
                    label={data.value}
                />
                <FormInput
                    type={data.type}
                    name={data.name}
                    placeholder={data.placeholder}
                    onChange={
                        e => props.onCommentsChange(
                            e,
                            data.structure,
                            data.rules
                        )}
                    value={selection}
                    err={props.error === 1
                        && props.validationErrors !== null
                        && data.name in props.validationErrors
                        ? 1
                        : 0
                    }
                />
            </div>
        )

}
```

The value of the input is the `selection` variable which is set like so:

```
let selection;
const data = {
    type: props.type,
    options: props.options,
    name: props.name,
    value: props.value,
    structure: props.structure,
    rules: props.rules,
    index: props.index,
    placeholder: props.placeholder,
    order: props.order,
    date: props.date,
    onDateChange: props.onDateChange,
    onFocusChangeHandler: props.onFocusChangeHandler,
    focused: props.focused,
};
const section = Object.entries(data.structure)[0][0];
```

From this, I'm trying to use an if statement which loops through like so and sets the `selection` variable to the value:

```
if (props.usersCurrentSelection !== null && props.usersCurrentSelection !== undefined) {
    console.log(props.usersCurrentSelection.data);
    console.log(section);
    console.log(props.usersCurrentSelection.data[section]);
    if (section in props.usersCurrentSelection.data) {
        Object.keys(props.usersCurrentSelection.data[section]).forEach(
            item => {
                let value = props.usersCurrentSelection.data[section][item];
                console.log(value);
                selection = value;
            }
        );
    }
}
```

the console logs return the following:

[image]

As you can see it's finding the value relevant to it's key in the loop. And since the text component is taking the `selection` variable as its value I'm unsure as to why this isn't populating?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You have to return values from your loop. use map instead of forEach

Comment: @gaditzkhori I've tried swapping out .forEach for .map, and I get the same results. Both from the return values and in terms of the values in the inputs no being populated.

Comment: I need to see the full code sorry.

Comment: In this code, you are setting `selection` for each key in `props.usersCurrentSelection.data[section]`. When you leave this `forEach`, selection will be set to whatever you set it to for the last key in your object (looks like `null` based on your logs). I haven't seen all of your code, but it looks like you should consider pulling the input-generation into its own component and passing it the `data` it needs, including one selection per key in `data[section]`.

Comment: Actually, what do you expect to happen, and what is actually happening? Are you expecting this code to generate one text input with a string value? Multiple text inputs, each with a string value? It's not trivial to understand your intentions or the actual output from the snippets you've provided. Lastly, you may want to make sure `washing_machine` has a string value, then test this again to see if your text input gets that value. Another thing you can do is `console.log(selection)` right before your `switch` to see what the variable is set to at that point.

Comment: @tex Thanks for the input. What I expect to happen is multiple text inputs have each their own string data from that object. So I think you could be right in what you first pointed out being that the last value in that object `washing_machine` is null and therefore no data is actually getting populated, if `washing_machine` had data, it would set them ALL to its value. Damn. Perhaps I should try your initial suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This is some pseudo code to show the approach I would probably take, based on your recent comment:

```
const Input = props => {
  // your switch statement goes here
}


const SectionFields = props => {
  const { type, options, name, value, structure = {}, rules, index, placeholder, order, date, onDateChange, onFocusChangeHandler, focused } = props
  const usersCurrentSelection = props.usersCurrentSelection || { data: {} }
  const section = Object.keys(structure)[0]

  const data = { type, options, name, value, structure, rules, index, placeholder, order, date, onDateChange, onFocusChangeHandler, focused }

  const itemsInSection = Object.values(usersCurrentSelection)

  return itemsInSection.length > 0
    ? (
      <>
        itemsInSection.map(([key, val]) => (
            <Input data={data} item={val} />
        ))
      </>
    )
    : null
}


const Form = props => (
  <>
    <SectionFields /*{props.section1 here}*/ />
    <SectionFields /*{props.section2 here}*/ />
    <SectionFields /*{props.section3 here}*/ />
  </>
)
```

This is probably too simplistic for your needs, but it might point you in the right direction. It's still a little hard to be certain what the entire, finished form is supposed to look like, and how the underlying data is organized.